# Why do I have two Healthy (Recovery Partitions)

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning

I am just starting to install Linux Mint on my new Acer E 15.  It came with Windows 8.1.  When I started to make the partition, I saw that there are three recovery drives:

- one Health (EFI System Partition)
- and two Healthy (Recovery Partitions)

I am hoping that I can delete the 14.22GB recovery partition to reclaim the space on it.  Can I do that?  How?

---

Other info:

- Installing Linux Mint but I want to dual boot.  I don't want to do anything that would compromise my windows install.

[image]

Comment: Exact model is E5-573-55W1

Answer (score 1):

Your machine. model E5-573-55W1, is Canadian in origin. Therefore, I suggest you go to their [website](http://www.acer.ca/ac/en/CA/content/ask-acer), enter its serial number, as their website demands the S/N to get any information from them.

In general, one of those recovery partitions can be deleted if you write the content off to a USB flashdrive. Me, I would make two copies, one on each of two flash drives, as flash drives do fail. How to do that? Either step through this [Microsoft generic procedure](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive), or when you reach Acer via the first weblink above, , tell the Acer rep you received the machine with no recovery media, and therefore you want to make one.